# Creating an unwanted composite key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I researched a lot but couldn't find the right keywords I guess.

When JPA creates the corresponding table to the class below. The table generation script is below as well. I don't understand why does it create a composite key. I want it to create a key based on just `id`.

- It makes a composite key based on `role_id` and `permission_id`.
- And assigns a default expression to the `role_id` which is `nextval('role_permissions_role_id_seq'::regclass)`

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_permissions")
public class RolePermission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Permission permission;

    protected RolePermission() {
    }

    public RolePermission(Role role, Permission permission) {
        this.role = role;
        this.permission = permission;
    }
}
```

```sql
create table role_permissions
(
    id            integer not null,
    permission_id integer not null,
    role_id       serial,
    primary key (role_id, permission_id),
    constraint fkegdk29eiy7mdtefy5c7eirr6e
        foreign key (permission_id) references permissions,
    constraint fkn5fotdgk8d1xvo8nav9uv3muc
        foreign key (role_id) references roles
);

alter table role_permissions
    owner to postgres;
```

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions")
public class Permission extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_permissions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles;

    protected Permission() {
    }

    public Permission(String name, String displayName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int level;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "role_permissions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Role(String name, int level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see the `Role` and `Permission` entities, too.  But my first guess would be that a direct many-to-many relationship is declared between them.  If so, then it's not clear to me what purpose your `RolePermission` entity serves.  It's also unclear to me why the key structure chosen is wrong (other than that it doesn't seem to match the annotations): do you *intend* to allow multiple distinct `RolePermission` entities for the same (`Role`, `Permission`) pair?

Comment: I added the role and permission entities. For your last question: No, I don't want to allow multiple pairs. Other than that I couldn't really understand what you meant.

Comment: `Set<Permission> permissions` - you have defined that  each `Role` has unique set of `Permission`'s, so, yes, Hibernate assumes there should be unique constraint in DB in order to support that restriction.

Comment: Oh, thanks. After changing ```Set``` to ```List``` it worked.

Comment: @CandoğuşYılmaz, if there should not be duplicate (`Role`, `Permission`) pairs then that should be enforced by appropriate constraints on the `role_permissions` table.  The most natural approach to that would be for that table to have a composite PK consisting of `role_id` and `permission_id`, instead of the surrogate key you are now assigning.

Comment: Moreover, you are asking for trouble by using the same table (`role_permissions`) as both a join table for a relationship and as an entity table.  Are you planning additional attributes for `RolePermission`?  If not, then you should probably just eliminate it altogether.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I'm planning to add more attributes. Since you mention it I will make it a composite PK. I was wondering why does it create the table like that. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, you should eliminate the direct relationship between `Role` and `Permission`.  Instead, give each of those entities a one-to-many relationship with `RolePermission`.  I promise that this will save you grief.

Comment: I see and I'll do it, thanks. I'd like to learn If you can shortly explain why current relationship approach is bad?

Answer (score 1):

The table is keyed as you observe because

1. You are using the `role_permissions` table *both* as an entity table for `RolePermission` and as a join table for the `Role`:`Permission` relationship, and
2. you have explicitly declared a surrogate PK field on the entity, and
3. you have declared the `Role.permissions` relationship field as a `Set`, which the DB generator tries to enforce via the join table's key.

You will cause yourself trouble by using the same table for an entity and a relationship.  That redundancy produces abundant opportunities for the object model to fall out of sync with the database, and that is virtually certain to manifest as application bugs.  Since apparently you want `RolePermission` to have attributes of its own, in addition to its two relationships, you should resolve the situation by breaking the direct many-to-many relationship between `Role` and `Permission`, along these lines:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    private String name;
    private int level;

    @OneToMany
    private List<RolePermission> rolePermissions;
}

@Entity
public class RolePermission {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Role role;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Permission permission;
}

@Entity
public class Permission {
    private String name;
    private String displayName;

    @OneToMany
    private List<RolePermission> permisionRoles;
}
```